# How to get week start date in scala

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I wrote the below code to get the Monday date for the date passed, Basically created an udf to pass a date and get it's monday date

```
def calculate_weekstartUDF = udf((pro_rtc:String)=>{
  val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(pro_rtc)
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.setTime(df)
  cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)
  //Get this Monday date
  val Period=cal.getTime()
})
```

Using the above UDF in below code
`flattendedJSON.withColumn("weekstartdate",calculate_weekstartUDF($"pro_rtc")).show()`

is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: could you post the exact date format?

Comment: Yes, there certainly is a better way (at least one). I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

Try with this approach using **`date_sub,next_day`** functions in spark.

***Explanation:***

```
date_sub(
        next_day('dt,"monday"), //get next monday date
   7)) //substract week from the date
```

**`Example:`**

```
val df =Seq(("2019-08-06")).toDF("dt")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("week_strt_day",date_sub(next_day('dt,"monday"),7)).show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+----------+-------------+
|        dt|week_strt_day|
+----------+-------------+
|2019-08-06|   2019-08-05|
+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Smart and simple

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Java 8 Date API :

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.{TemporalField, WeekFields}
import java.util.Locale

def calculate_weekstartUDF =
 (pro_rtc:String)=>{
   val localDate = LocalDate.parse(pro_rtc);  // By default parses a string in YYYY-MM-DD format.
   val dayOfWeekField = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault).dayOfWeek()
   localDate.`with`(dayOfWeekField, 1)  
  }
```

Of course, specify other thing than `Locale.getDefault` if you want to use another `Locale`.

Comment: got this error `Schema for type java.time.LocalDate is not supported` BTW input is in unix time format

Comment: [Schema for type Any is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121649/schema-for-type-any-is-not-supported), perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( "2019-01-23" )
.with(
    TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-01-21

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Here is Java-syntax example code. (I don't know Scala)

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
```

To move from that date to another, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). You can find several in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

Specify a day-of-week using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum, predefining seven objects, one for each day of the week.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
LocalDate previousMonday = ld.with( ta ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/17fVsI).

> Monday, January 21, 2019

If the starting date happened to be a Monday, and you want to stay with that, use the alternate adjuster, [`previousOrSame`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame(java.time.DayOfWeek)).

Comment: @OleV.V. I had mentioned that at the end. The Question is not clearly written, and I don’t see which way the author intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In my example, 'pro_rtc' is in seconds. Adjust if needed.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataFrame
   .withColumn("Date", to_date(from_unixtime(col("pro_rtc"))))
   .withColumn("Monday", expr("date_sub(Date, dayofweek(Date) - 2)"))
```

That way, you're also utilizing Spark's query engine and avoiding UDF's latency

Comment: `date_sub(Date, dayofweek(Date) - 1)` will give Sunday but not Monday, anyways thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Right. I'll fix it

Comment: even now there is a problem `dayofweek` only works to get sundays

Comment: Are you sure? I checked it for all 7 days

Answer (score 0):

The [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria) `beginningOfWeek` and `endOfWeek` functions are the easiest way to solve this problem.  They're also the most flexible because they can easily be configured for different week end dates.

Suppose you have this dataset:

```
+----------+
| some_date|
+----------+
|2020-12-27|
|2020-12-28|
|2021-01-03|
|2020-12-12|
|      null|
+----------+
```

Here's how to compute the beginning of the week and the end of the week, assuming the week ends on a Wednesday:

```scala
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.functions._
df
  .withColumn("end_of_week", endOfWeek(col("some_date"), "Wed"))
  .withColumn("beginning_of_week", beginningOfWeek(col("some_date"), "Wed"))
  .show()
```

Here are the results:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| some_date|end_of_week|beginning_of_week|
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|2020-12-27| 2020-12-30|       2020-12-24|
|2020-12-28| 2020-12-30|       2020-12-24|
|2021-01-03| 2021-01-06|       2020-12-31|
|2020-12-12| 2020-12-16|       2020-12-10|
|      null|       null|             null|
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

See [this file](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/mrpowers/spark/daria/sql/functions.scala) for the underlying implementations.  [This post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/week-end-start-dayofweek-next-day/) explains these functions in greater detail.

Comment: grateful if you could share any thoughts on this